# Creating Clustered Columnstore Indexes in SSDT for Visual Studio 2013

Tags: indexing, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools, columnstore

I have created a data warehouse with numerous fact and dimension tables.  For each of the fact tables, I am trying to create a clustered columnstore index, but I keep running into an issue. I use the following statement to try and accomplish this.

CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX CStoreIX_FactAssessment
ON FactAssessment

For some reason, it keeps highlighting the word CREATE and gives the message "SQL70001: This statement is not recognized in this context."  I have made sure that I downloaded the latest version of SSDT from the TOOLS>Extensions and Updates menu, but still have the problem.  I am trying to keep all of my database code such as my creation of indexes, constraints, etc. in this one solution rather than moving to management studio to add them.  Has anyone else come across this problem or does anyone have any ideas what I may be doing wrong?  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is it a database project (.sqlproj) or one of the BI projects? You mention they are fact and dimension tables so I'm guessing BI? In that case you need to install SSDT-BI for VS2013 from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42313

Comment: No this is a SQL project, and in this project, I create all of my fact and dimension tables as well as the indexes, keys, etc...  I have ssdt-bi installed as well and use it to move data from a source system to this data warehouse.  I can go into management studio and add the clustered columnstore indexes there, but was curious why the latest version of SSDT for visual studio 2013 doesn't recognize it.

Comment: And one more check- the project's target SQL version is SQL Server 2014?

Comment: Ah ha!  That's what I had forgot to do.  It was still set to target SQL Server 2012.  Thanks for mentioning that.  Sometimes it's the simple things!